# Magento ignore special price for certain stores/different getFinalPrice on list and view

Tags: magento

I'm looking to have special prices ignored for some stores, so far I've changed `/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php` by adding extra conditions to:

```
public static function calculateSpecialPrice($finalPrice, $specialPrice, $specialPriceFrom, $specialPriceTo, $store = null)
{       
    if (!is_null($specialPrice) && $specialPrice != false && (extra conditions using store code)) {
        if (Mage::app()->getLocale()->isStoreDateInInterval($store, $specialPriceFrom, $specialPriceTo)) {
            $finalPrice     = min($finalPrice, $specialPrice);
        }
    }
    return $finalPrice;
}
```

And this works great almost everywhere. However on list view, and search results, where I've called

```
$this->helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),true,true)
```

It seems to be using a different method, and I can't track it down - any thoughts?

> **UPDATE**:
>   The very same method called on the view.phtml page works correctly, so it is something to do with the differing methods called on each page.
>
> **ALSO**:
>   I know I could just use something other than getFinalPrice on list, since it works in the cart/item page already, but I need it to not break things like sort by price, and price filters.

Comment: You will find getFinalPrice methods here:
`Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price::getFinalPrice()
Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::getFinalPrice() Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price::getFinalPrice() Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped_Price::getFinalPrice() Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price::getFinalPrice() Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getFinalPrice()
Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Data_Abstract::getFinalPrice() Mage_CatalogIndex_Model_Data_Grouped::getFinalPrice()`

Comment: Thanks for the list danny. I had done a search through the files too, was just hoping for a more 'at source' solution I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the price as required on the list page too, I needed to change `Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php` as well.

```
public function getFinalPrice($qty=null)
{

    if (same store code conditions)
        $price = $this->_getData('final_price');
    else $price = $this->getPrice();
    if ($price !== null) {
        return $price;
    }
    return $this->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice($qty, $this);
}
```

Comment: bad idea. `final_price` != `price`. You will have problems if `special_price` and `tier_price` isset for product.

Comment: The idea is that `final_price != price`. I specifically want to ignore a discounted price for specific stores.